# Basic Authentication - Hashing Algorithm and Header injection - security concerns

Tags: http, authentication

My understanding of Basic Authentication is that it stores the username:password pair in the request headers, which are then returned on subsequent responses from the server.

Questions:

1. What hashing algorithm does the browser use to create the initial username:password hash which is sent to the server for verification?
2. Should every request on the server run the username:password pair through verification or is it enough to just see that there is something in the Authorization header and accept that because it is there then the session has been already verified?
3. (relating to 2) Is it possible to insert into the Authorization header any old string and thus trick the server into believe the session has been authenticated?

I know in theory we should not ever use Basic Auth, but in some circumstances it makes sense .

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

No hashing occurs, the credentials are present in plain text, they are just base 64 encoded to fit in the character range allowed for headers. Every request must include this header for every resource where the server expects an authenticated user.

So, when you capture a request, you can use the header to spoof requests as the user that made the initial request.

HTTPS will prevent eavesdropping, but that doesn't make it much safer. See also [Is BASIC-Auth secure if done over HTTPS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https).